# How to switch window controls to the left (Gnome Shell)?

Tags: gnome-shell, window-buttons

Is there a way to the switch gnome-shell window buttons to the left? I've gotten so used to them being on the left that them being on the right has thrown me way off.

(gnome shell has them defaulted to the right corner)

Comment: You've only said left. Apparently, they're on the left side and you want them on the left side.

Comment: Leave the on the left. They're just fine there, since if you'd look at hot map of the screen, you'd see that mouse pointer is more often located on the left part of the screen, not on the right — it means it'd track less to the buttons.

Comment: @Poige isn't that just because that's where the buttons are? On Windows, surely the map shows it more on the right?

Answer (score 31, accepted):

**For 10.10**

The more simple way to do that is:
<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>F2</kbd> →  `gconf-editor`

Navigate to apps →  metacity →  general, and double click on the entry: `button_layout`, then enter `close,minimize,maximize:`. You can also use `spacer` at some point to add a space.

**For 11.04 and 11.10**

<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>F2</kbd> →  `gconf-editor`

Navigate to desktop →  gnome →  shell →  windows, and double click on the entry: `button_layout`, then enter `close,minimize,maximize:`. You can also use `spacer` at some point to add a space.

Comment: If you want the buttons on the *left*, then the colon needs to be at the end of the list instead of the beginning.

Comment: on 11.10, I had to make the change in desktop --> gnome --> shell --> windows.

To restart gnome shell, press Alt-F2, and type rt.

Comment: The approach for 10.10 also works for 12.04, at least when `gnome-classic` is being used as the session manager.

Answer (score 71):

**For Ubuntu 12.04 and newer**

You will need dconf-editor, which is part of the dconf-tools package. Install it first:

[dconf-tools](https://apps.ubuntu.com/cat/applications/dconf-tools)

Start dconf-editor:

<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>F2</kbd> → dconf-editor

Go to org → gnome → shell → overrides → button layout. Change it to `close,minimize,maximize:`

No need to restart the shell.

Note: This also changes the cancel button in the overlay mode.

**For 13.10 and higher**

As per a few users, it may require a shell restart. Thank you all for pointing that out.

**For 15.10 and higher**

The schema is now `org.gnome.desktop.wm.preferences` as per [this comment](https://askubuntu.com/questions/9867/how-to-switch-window-controls-to-the-left-gnome-shell#comment1078365_113995).

Comment: `close,maximize,minimize:menu` worked for me too.

Comment: This doesn't work on 13.10 ubuntu-gnome-desktop

Comment: @Alvar: use gnome-tweak-tool and see if it helps you. There is an option available to switch windows as far as I remember.

Comment: there is no option in tweak tool already checked that...

Comment: had to restart gnome-shell 3.10 in ubuntu 14.04 for the settings to be applied

Comment: Alt+F2 type r and enter. restart was a must for me to see the changes.

Comment: For Ubuntu 15.10, in dconf-editor, the schema is: "org.gnome.desktop.wm.preferences"

Answer (score 62):

While technically not gnome-shell, if you're using gnome-flashback or gnome-flashback-no-effects the key is located at:

```
org -> gnome -> desktop -> wm -> preferences -> button-layout
```

Changing it to:

```
close,minimize,maximize:
```

should give you what you want.

You can use the command:

```
gsettings set  org.gnome.desktop.wm.preferences button-layout 'close,minimize,maximize:'
```

to get this done quicker.

Comment: For Google Chrome under gnome shell, I didn't have the metacity>button-layout key entry, This code worked for me:  gconftool-2 --set /apps/metacity/general/button_layout --type string "close,minimize,maximize:"

Comment: This was the location for standard Gnome 3 on my installation as well.
(GNOME Shell 3.18.4 / Ubuntu 16.04)

Comment: the simplest and quickest way is to use the command,it worked for me flawlessly in ubuntu 18.04 including for chrome app that I am using to read SO right now,the effects took place in real time.

Comment: Love the best "gsettings set  org.gnome.desktop.wm.preferences button-layout 'close,minimize,maximize:' "

Answer (score 20):

If you're using Gnome Shell and you want the window buttons on the left, use this command:

```
dconf write /org/gnome/shell/overrides/button-layout "'close,minimize,maximize:'"
```

Then restart the shell if needed: press <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>F2</kbd>, type <kbd>r</kbd> and press <kbd>Enter</kbd>.

Comment: It is in gnome-tweak: `Advanced Settings (application) > Shell > Arrangement of Buttons > pick all`

Comment: Except there it won't let you change them to the left, which is what OP was asking for.

Comment: This does't work for Ubuntu 12.04

Comment: @BuZZ-dEE: Didn't work in 13.04 either, so I fixed it by adding explicit quotes as required by GVariant format. Also, the shell didn't need to be restarted for me (Gnome 3.4). Perhaps this was only needed in earlier versions of Gnome 3.

Answer (score 14):

If you have installed [Ubuntu Tweak](http://ubuntu-tweak.com/), go to *Window Manager* and change the *Place* from left to right or vice versa. This will change all windows' Titlebar button layout, not only gnome shell.

[image]

Answer (score 10):

### Gnome version 3.10, Using 13.04 and 13.10

If you upgrade Gnome to 3.10 you may notice a change in window decorations.
Gnome version 3.10 is moving towards *Client Side Decorations*(CSD for short)  in all of the **Core apps**.

In these apps the close button is integrated into the program window and does not use the normal window decorations.

[image]

As [Web Upd8](http://www.webupd8.org/2013/09/see-whats-new-in-gnome-310-video.html) states:

> Another pretty major change in the latest GNOME 3.10 is the
>   introduction of **"header bars" or "client side decorations"**. These
>   decorations use the GTK+ toolkit and theme engine:
>
> As you can see, the close button is now displayed inline with the
>   toolbar which saves spaces but unfortunately it also creates an even
>   bigger discrepancy between GNOME core apps and the other applications,
>   because only the core GNOME apps use these client side decorations.

---

Some applications that have CSD may respect the environment variable `GTK_CSD=0` (a variable used to "try out" CSD in eariler gnome versions with =1)  for more information about Environment variables: https://help.ubuntu.com/community/EnvironmentVariables especially the section: [Launching desktop application with an environment variable](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/EnvironmentVariables#Launching_desktop_application_with_an_environment_variable) to experiment with programs adding something like this to a launcher:

```
Exec=env GTK_CSD=# gedit
```

substuting "#" with 1 or 0 for on and off, and gedit with program of choice

However it seems with **Nautilus** in 3.10 the variable **Does not work.**

---

[Simply put](http://comments.gmane.org/gmane.comp.gnome.nautilus/14479):

> In 3.10 it's going to have a close button at the top right no matter
>   what[...]

---

#### So what can you do?

- Stay at an older version of Gnome. Development is still progressing and the Gnome version in the repositories works just fine. It may be likely that options will be added in the future.
- Replace Nautilus with **Nemo**. Form most cases Nemo looks and acts like Nautilus:

  [image]

  To Install:

  1. Open Terminal put the following command:
  2. `sudo apt-get install nemo`
  3. [Make nemo the default file browser](https://askubuntu.com/questions/260244/make-nemo-as-default-file-browser)

Comment: What about editing Nautilus' source code and re-compiling?

Comment: The nasty part is that not only nautilus has the big close button on the right side but more applications like Clocks, Music etc.

Comment: What about Ubuntu-gnome 13.10? How do I fix the buttons on the left side there?

Comment: This one is about gnome 3.10, or the "client side decorations"

Comment: So you can't use client side decorations/unmodified GNOME _and_ move the window buttons? :(

Answer (score 8):

**In Ubuntu 18.04 and later there are multiple options:**

1. You can now just install GNOME Tweak Tool (which is a helpful tool anyway) from the *Software Center* or by running in a terminal:

   ```
   sudo apt install gnome-tweaks
   ```

   and in the menu *Window Titlebars* change *Placement* to *Left*.

   [image: Tweaks]
2. **[Dconf-editor/tool change](https://askubuntu.com/a/974294/30631)** still works:

   ```
   /org/gnome/desktop/wm/preferences/button-layout
   ```

   set to `close,minimize,maximize`.
3. And the **[terminal](https://askubuntu.com/a/974294/30631)** option, too:

   ```
   gsettings set  org.gnome.desktop.wm.preferences button-layout 'close,minimize,maximize:'
   ```

Answer (score 4):

Do what hrhnick said, except use this command instead:

```
gconftool-2 -s /desktop/gnome/shell/windows/button_layout -t String minimize,maximize,close:" where "minimize,maximize,close:
```

Then hit <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>F2</kbd> and type

```
gnome-shell --replace
```

and hit enter

Answer (score 4):

The workspace window view of gnome shell uses the same button layout as the window manager (albeit only for the close button). ([relevant code](http://bazaar.launchpad.net/~ubuntu-branches/ubuntu/oneiric/gnome-shell/oneiric/view/1.1.25/js/ui/workspace.js#L462))

If you set your close window buttons to the left using gconf, the close button on the window preview in workspace view will also display on the left.

Using gconf-editor, change /desktop/gnome/shell/windows/button_layout to `close,minimize,maximize:` and re-login to see the change.

Comment: Yep, I can confirm that that is exactly how I have that setting in my gconf, but the close button is still on the right. Maybe it's a bug.  Note that it was working properly until I installed some gnome-shell theme extension.  I'm betting that relevent js file got overwritten.  I'll look into it.  Thanks.

Comment: The workspace.js file in my /usr/share/gnome-shell/js/ui/ folder is different than the one you linked me to, but it still contains that same function, albeit in a different place.  Doing a direct replace of the workspace.js file with the one in the bzr repository you linked to  just breaks gnome shell.  Something in the theme extention must be making some assumptions.

Comment: I expect we'll see many problems with shell extensions that just monkey patch the UI functions and lead to confusing results. I'm pretty sure what you are seeing is an extension that positions that button. Can you provide a link to the theme extension please? **Edit:** Also, which version of ubuntu are you using, and is the gnome-shell package from that version's ubuntu repository?

Comment: I'm using 11.10, and I'm using the gnome shell extension repository from here (http://www.webupd8.org/2011/10/official-gnome-shell-extensions.html). THe ppa is here: ppa:webupd8team/gnome3

Comment: I've also just discovered that it's not the theme extension that's causing the problem is the Native Window Placement extension.  Thanks for sending me down the right path.  I'll submit a bug report to the extension developer.

Answer (score 4):

**17.04 and 17.10 (Gnome 3.22)**

The beginning is as in this answer: https://askubuntu.com/a/113995/286561

> You will need dconf-editor, which is part of the dconf-tools package.
>   Install it first:
>
> [dconf-tools](https://apps.ubuntu.com/cat/applications/dconf-tools)
>
> Start dconf-editor:
>
> <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>F2</kbd> → dconf-editor

But the key is `/org/gnome/desktop/wm/preferences/button-layout`, the default is: `appmenu:cloe`, I've changed it to `close,minimize,maximize:appmenu`. (`appmenu` doesn't seem to have an effect.)

[image]

I've you want to do it on the terminal you can do it as pointed out in this answer: https://askubuntu.com/a/377811/286561

```
gsettings set  org.gnome.desktop.wm.preferences button-layout 'close,minimize,maximize:'
```

Answer (score 3):

This command should work: `gconftool-2 --set /apps/metacity/general/button_layout  --type string "menu:minimize,maximize,close"` (Assuming you want to move them from left to right, which is what I interpreted from your question...assuming move from left to left was a typo :-) ).

Comment: Actually, I wanted to move them from right to left.