# Move gnome shell window close button to left

Tags: gnome, window-buttons

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Switch gnome shell buttons to the left](https://askubuntu.com/questions/9867/switch-gnome-shell-buttons-to-the-left)

To be clear I'm not talking about the windows controls, but the little x button that shows up when your in the "expose" windows mode in gnome shell when you mouse over the activities button.

I've already used gconf to move the actual windows controls over to the left (ubuntu's change got me used to it, and now I like it), but that didn't move the x close button from the windows activity view.