# How can I get the buttons back on the left side in GNOME?

Tags: gnome, configuration, window-buttons

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How to switch window controls to the left?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/9867/how-to-switch-window-controls-to-the-left)

I installed Ubuntu 11.10 along with Gnome 3.2. Under Gnome 3.2, the window buttons for closing, minimizing and restoring are on the left side. I got used to (and like) the buttons being on the left hand side. How can I get those buttons back on the left side ?