# How do I get the minimize, maximize and close buttons to the left in GNOME Shell?

Tags: 11.10, gnome, window-buttons

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How to switch window controls to the left?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/9867/how-to-switch-window-controls-to-the-left)

When I try to move them to the left the minimize and the maximize buttons disappear and the only the close button moves to the left.

Comment: Related (for 10.10): http://askubuntu.com/questions/9867/switch-gnome-shell-buttons-to-the-left