# How to Move the Window Buttons from Right to Left in Gnome 3 using Ubuntu 12.04 (Precise Pangolin)

Tags: 12.04, gnome

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How to switch window controls to the left?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/9867/how-to-switch-window-controls-to-the-left)

I have Ubuntu 12.04 installed with Gnome 3 shell. I'm used to the window buttons being on the left side of the window from Unity and would like to incorporate this feature into my Gnome setup. I've tried Advanced Settings from the Software Center but there's no option to move the location of the window buttons. Any thoughts?