# I can't change windows buttons to the right side with Ubuntu Tweak

Tags: window-buttons, tweak

I am running Ubuntu 12.10 Quantal, and I have Ubuntu Tweak already installed. I am tring to change windows buttons to the right side. I choose option "Right" in UT (and nothing happens). When I close UT and open again, option "Left" is still selected. What's wrong with this?!

Sorry for my english, and thanks a lot for help.

Comment: Do you have to use Ubuntu Tweak?  There are lots of other ways..

Comment: No, of course not. This is one of few options which doesn't work, for example I can't change GTK Theme as well

Comment: See http://askubuntu.com/questions/9867/how-to-switch-window-controls-to-the-left

Answer (score 0):

Type the following code in terminal to change them.

```
gconftool-2 --set /apps/metacity/general/button_layout --type string menu:minimize,maximize,close
```