# Minimise button gone

Tags: gnome-classic

This is really weird. I just followed this tutorial:

http://ubuntuportal.com/2012/05/install-elementary-desktop-environment-in-ubuntu-12-04-lts.html

and it didn't work. My computer is all back to normal apart from the fact I have no minimise button. Yes I have searched but everyone is complaining about all the buttons. This is literally just minimise. Close is on the left, maximise is on the right and there is nothing else.

Comment: Do you still have the 'minimize' entry as seen from dconf-editor? See: http://askubuntu.com/questions/9867/how-to-switch-window-controls-to-the-left

Comment: Just added it and it works! Thanks! But maximize and minimize are over the right instead of left now

Comment: Scrap that. Used commas instead of semicolons and it worked.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The appearence, order, and location of the close, maximize, and minimize buttons are defined in the **dconf** path `/org/gnome/shell/overrides/button-layout` where windows button settings default to

```
close,minimize,maximize:
```

To edit this path I recommend to use **dconf-editor** and edit them from the GUI rather than from command line, as the terminology and paths of this keys had changed a lot and may change again in the future. From the GUI you will notice.

See also: [How to switch window controls to the left (Gnome Shell)?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/9867/how-to-switch-window-controls-to-the-left)