# Move Gnome 3.10 window close button to left side

Tags: gnome, nautilus

How can I move the close window button from right to left side?

> [image]
>
> Nautilus

I upgrated the Gnome from 3.8 to Gnome 3.10.0.1.

I already moved the maximize, minimize and close buttons to left side with the following result:

> [image]
>
> Mozilla Firefox

...but it seems that the Nautilus (for example) close button is not moved. Why? How can I move it?

[The answers posted to this question](https://askubuntu.com/q/9867/148451) didn't solve the problem.

Comment: @Mitch Ah, I forgot to say that I didn't find the answer [here](http://askubuntu.com/q/9867/148451)...

Comment: This would be the same in 13.04 and gnome 3.10, so I'm editing to be generic and voting to reopen. The reason is it is a change in gnome design.

Comment: @Mateo Thanks! Like we wrote in chat, I also think that it's a Gnome feature, not a bug.

Comment: @Mateo - if this is a change in design, then this question should be duplicated against the master Q - you should add a 13.10 answer on the master Q.

Comment: @fossfreedom Ok, but please add the Gnome 3.10 solution... And again: it's not related to the Ubuntu version but to Gnome version.

Comment: @Johnツ - I'll leave this to Mateo to do since Mateo recognises the issue.  Yes the answer should be tagged 13.10+Gnome 3.10

Comment: I bet it's hard coded into Nautilus, like Chromium. Might have some code wrangling to do ;)

Comment: @Seth Yes, maybe... But it appears in other applications, so I think it's a new thing in Gnome 3.10. Also, I bet that it can be moved! :-)

Comment: Thanks @Mateo for [the solution you found](http://askubuntu.com/a/353846/148451)!