# Can you "fix" chrome's close, minimize, maximize buttons so they are on the left, and use ubuntu's theme?

Tags: google-chrome

Can you "fix" chrome's close, minimize, maximize buttons so they are on the left, and use ubuntu's theme?
I might actually use chrome then.

Comment: Select the option to Use GTK+ theme in the chrome settings. The 'Use system title bar and borders' setting hides the buttons when I go full screen on Ubuntu 18.04, so disable that.

Answer (score 38, accepted):

I believe there is an option to use "System title bars" under the settings on the "Hamburger Menu" on the upper-right hand corner in Chrome. Navigate to settings, the same screen where you would select for chrome to use the GTK+ theme, and the setting is in there.

As shown in this picture:

[image]

Comment: Which theme are you using?

Comment: You can also tell Chromium to use the GTK theme instead of the classic one

Comment: Thanks, it helped.

Comment: dont know why, but for me it helped just to disabling it

Answer (score 8):

The problem with @Jbuch14 answer is that it adds an extra bar on top of everything, so it's not a real solution. I dont want any extra bars, I just want Chrome's own buttons to be at right side. How to do it?

edit: Ok I figured it out! Instead of enabling "use system title bar...", you DISABLE it, and then run command

```
gconftool-2 --set /apps/metacity/general/button_layout --type string ":minimize,,maximize,close"
```

and voila! No double top bar, and buttons are Windows-style at right.

Comment: The problem reappeared in 15.10 using Chrome 49 on KDE and this fix does not help anymore. I suppose that windowing manager used for Chrome even it being a GTK app is not metacity but kwin. Is there any solution for this setup too?  The buttons are shown however when the window is not maximized.

Comment: For me, @juch14's solution worked just fine, I'm running 14.04 though

Comment: it doesn't work for me ubuntu 16.10  , does it has to do with the theme I'm using a different one , other than the default .

Comment: This is working fine on ubuntu 22.04. Google Chrome and the PWAs installed using the browser no longer have the titlebar buttons missing.

Answer (score 1):

Chrome and Ubuntu (Unity) uses different setting for positioning the window controls. Though Chrome popups always uses the system bars.

---

For Chrome controls: using [gconf-editor](https://apps.ubuntu.com/cat/applications/gconf-editor/) create/edit the key `button_layout` under `/apps/metacity/general` with value `close,minimize,maximize:`

---

For system controls: using [dconf-editor](https://apps.ubuntu.com/cat/applications/dconf-editor/) create/edit the key `button-layout` under `org.gnome.desktop.wm.preferences` with value `close,minimize,maximize:`

Note: **works from 12.04 until 13.10**, since 14.04 you can't change window controls side as stated in [this answer](https://askubuntu.com/questions/174292/how-can-i-move-all-the-window-controls-to-the-right-or-left/451330#451330).

---

To use Ubuntu theme use the options under Appearance in Chrome settings as [pointed by @Jbuch14](https://askubuntu.com/questions/505148/#505151). When using system bars you are subjected to the note above.

Comment: No need of all this. @Jbuch14's answer is the simplest tweak you can ever do.

Comment: nope, not if we want the Chrome styling of the buttons, and not having an a bar which might be ugly.

Comment: between, it does not work for me @Sançao, it only works for normal windows, not for chrome.

Comment: @sidney in a quick search I find out there is issues in some versions, I provided additional info in the answer. I'm now using Ubuntu 14.04 and Chrome 41 and these settings make no effect

Comment: Thanks for the answer @Sanção. However I do not think that this is quite right. I'm currently using Ubuntu 14.04 using the Mate Environment, a fork of Gnome 2. It should behave as the Gnome fallback. I can have the buttons to the left on any windows, but not on chrome. As stated in this screenshot: http://image.noelshack.com/fichiers/2015/16/1429011863-screenshot-255.png

Comment: just tried again, and modifying the `/apps/metacity/general` setting move only chrome's window controls (on Unity). Seems there's some other setting for your environment, try `/desktop/gnome/shell/windows/button_layout` in gconf (reference: http://askubuntu.com/questions/9867/#9916), if not found you can try ctrl+f `button_layout` (underscore) and `button-layout`(hyphen)

Comment: I already had it setted to the good option. But chrome's buttons are still to the right :/

Comment: I already did the same on dconf-editor, still to no avail

Comment: @sidney I don't know how to help any further, I tried the mentioned setting on Gnome Flashback and it worked. I couldn't install Mate env to test, due to network restrictions.

Comment: @Sanção thanks you anyways, that is kind enough to go that far for an answer :) It has been a very long time that I got accustomed to that disposition inconsistency. I guess one will find the solution one day, I will wait until then ;)