# Hide chromium's title bar using Compiz

Tags: compiz, chromium, titlebar

Ever since updating to Chromium v65 or 18.04 (not sure which one is the culprit), unchecking the "[Use system title bar and borders](https://askubuntu.com/questions/505148/can-you-fix-chromes-close-minimize-maximize-buttons-so-they-are-on-the-left)" doesn't work anymore. The title bar will shows up once I unmaximize it, GTK or classic theme.

Answer (score 0):

If you use Compiz, Chromium's title bar can be hidden by *not* decorating it.

To do this, go to CompizConfig Settings Manager, scroll down to the "Effects" section and click "Window Decorations". On the "Decoration windows" field, replace `any` with `!class=Chromium-browser`.

modified from [this](http://www.webupd8.org/2009/11/gain-space-by-removing-maximized.html) guide.