# Has or will Bug #1568490 ever be addressed?

Tags: unity, 16.04, window-control

I am an old and ornery guy that has had the window controls on the right of window since the Windows 3.1 days. Along comes this new fandangled Unity thing and it moves the buttons to the left. I would love to give this Unity a chance, but my mind just will not let me look for the window controls on the left.
Seriously, has [this bug](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/unity-settings-daemon/+bug/1568490) been/or will ever be addressed or is my choice to go with another DE?

Comment: It's possible now:

Comment: @Zacharee1 i think tweak tool changed since 16.4 i install it but  their's no `Window Controls`

Comment: @MohamedSlama it probably did change, but the setting might still be there. Check in other menus.

Comment: @Zacharee1 no thing like that on unity `tweak` , `gconf` or `dconf`

Comment: the best answer here yes it's a bug and not solved , but if you really want this install new desktop check this answer for more information http://askubuntu.com/a/451330/464430

Comment: Hmm. It seems as though 16.04 has blocked the feature again: http://askubuntu.com/questions/764166/how-to-move-window-buttons-to-right-in-ubuntu-16-04

Comment: You can try alternative desktop environments like GNOME or Xfce.

Answer (score 0):

Yes it's a **bug** and not solved maybe this feature blocked in the new version of unity , but if you really want this, install new desktop check this [answer](https://askubuntu.com/a/451330/464430) for more information.

Answer (score -1):

Install unity tweak tool:

```
 sudo apt-get install unity-tweak-tool
```

open the unity tweak tool from the dash. Then, from the ***appearance*** > ***window controls***, set the controls to be aligned to the right.

Comment: There's no "appearance > window controls" in my Unity Tweak.

Comment: If there's a duplicate that's been suggested, it's usually not best to essentially copy the answer from it.